# Solving in ODE45 -Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

I have an ODE, `y'=y^2+y`; So, I wrote an script as:

```
foo=@(y)(y.^2+y);
[x y]=ode45(foo,[1 4],1);
```

But it returns the following error:

```
Error using @(y)(y.^2+y)
Too many input arguments.

Error in odearguments (line 88)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1}
to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 114)
[neq, tspan, ntspan, next, t0, tfinal, tdir, y0, f0,
odeArgs, odeFcn, ...
```

I must have made some mistake in defining function.
I appreciate any comments and suggestions.

Comment: The ode solvers can handle systems that are time varying. That is, where the derivative is a function of both "t" and the state "x". As Eitan shows below, you **must** pass the "t" parameter even if your derivative function doesn't use it!

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html):

> All solvers solve systems of equations in the form `y′ = f(t,y)` or problems that involve a mass matrix, `M(t,y)y′ = f(t,y).`

Your function accepts only one variable `y`, whereas it must accept two: `t` and `y`. So, if your ODE is `y′ = y2 + y`, define `foo` in the following manner:

```
foo = @(t, y)(y .^ 2 + y);
```

and it should work.